# How to add one program(for example python program) (run it when linux startup) and add some file to live cd?

Tags: linux, live-cd

I would like to have a CD with a custom Linux installation, When this linux was booted the

hard disk formate and create partitions(tree ex3 and one swap) and copy one image to parition

hard disk.

How to add one program(for example python program) and add some file to live cd?

tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this link for get answer:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Answer (score 0):

Starting on boot you should look at `/etc/rc.local`. To add files to a live-cd you'll have to look up the docs for the various live-cd build tools, as for many of them you can't just add a file to ISO, it has to be in a compressed image inside it.